# Cognos report column with zero width appearing

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a Cognos report with a few calculation columns that are necessary not to be hidden otherwise there are alignment problems. The grouping is quite intricate and requires these columns to be there.

In order to hide the calculation columns I set their width to zero pixels. In the HTML version of the report the column does not appear, however in other versions like in Excel there is an empty column appearing. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try setting the Box Type to 'None'? This will take it out of the page render. By the way, you might be able to add the column to the list's Properties property. When you do that it gets included in the query sent to the data source even if it's included as a column.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to give it a go

Comment: Hi I tried what you said but there is another problem now. I have nested columns and if I do what you suggested the header row becomes misaligned. Any more ideas?

Comment: You can apply similar formatting to the headers.

Comment: What Damienknight said is correct. You have to apply the Box Type: None setting to the headers as well.

Comment: Like @Johnsonium said, though, you may be able to just add the list items to the Property list and then remove them from the list entirely.  That's the usual way to do it.  Alternately, you could leave the columns in place, select the List Column from the ancestor menu and set the entire column to Render: No?